# img src=blob: how to get the picture?

Tags: blob

I've an image displayed as blob:

```
<img id="imgcaptmobile" width="487" src="blob:http%3A//www.mysite.com/ab750f54-ecb4-4dc9-8d9d-4e28c4a41262">
```

How can I upload the picture as a file with jquery ajax please?...

Comment: If you could find a way to retrieve the blob that the url was built on you can then pass it to XMLHttpRequest.send

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
var blobURL = "blob:http%3A//www.mysite.com/ab750f54-ecb4-4dc9-8d9d-4e28c4a41262";
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    var picture = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("picture", picture);
    $.ajax({
      "url": "The Upload URL",
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      "data": data,
      success: function(response) {
        //handle the response
      }
  });
}
image.src = blobURL;
```

```html
<img src='blob:http%3A//www.mysite.com/ab750f54-ecb4-4dc9-8d9d-4e28c4a41262' />
```

## and don't forget to decode the data from the server side ...